# How does Hive 'alter table <table name> concatenate' work?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, orc

I have `n(large)` number of small sized orc files which i want to merge into `k(small)` number of large orc files.

This is done using `alter table table_name concatenate` command in Hive.

I want to understand how does Hive implement this.
I'm looking to implement this using Spark with any changes if required.

Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [AlterTable/PartitionConcatenate](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterTable/PartitionConcatenate):

If the table or partition contains many small RCFiles or ORC files, then the above command will merge them into larger files. In case of RCFile the merge happens at block level whereas for ORC files the merge happens at stripe level thereby avoiding the overhead of decompressing and decoding the data.

Also [ORC Stripes](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+ORC#LanguageManualORC-Stripes):

The body of ORC files consists of a series of stripes. Stripes are
large (typically ~200MB) and independent of each other and are often
processed by different tasks. The defining characteristic for columnar
storage formats is that the data for each column is stored separately
and that reading data out of the file should be proportional to the
number of columns read.
In ORC files, each column is stored in several streams that are stored
next to each other in the file. For example, an integer column is
represented as two streams PRESENT, which uses one with a bit per
value recording if the value is non-null, and DATA, which records the
non-null values. If all of a column's values in a stripe are non-null,
the PRESENT stream is omitted from the stripe. For binary data, ORC
uses three streams PRESENT, DATA, and LENGTH, which stores the length
of each value. The details of each type will be presented in the
following subsections.

For implementing in Spark you can use [SparkSQL](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#sql) with the help of Spark Context:

```
scala> val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)

scala> sqlContext.sql("Your_hive_query_here")
```

Comment: FYI The `ALTER TABLE <table-spec> <partition-spec> CONCATENATE;` Hive SQL command is NOT supported by Spark SQL even in HiveContext.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that SparkSQL has a number of Hive SQL [commands which are not supported](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/73dd6cf9b558f9d752e1f3c13584344257ad7863/sql/catalyst/src/main/antlr4/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/parser/SqlBase.g4#L217).

`ALTER TABLE <tableIdentifier> [partitionSpec] CONCATENATE` is on that list, and has been from Spark 1, 2 to 3. It will likely continue to be unsupported from Spark until the day that the Hadoop ecosystem ships Hive with Spark as its default engine, and even then, this may become deprecated.